# Get data between two '/' using re module

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to extract some text from a URL path, but I have little knowledge of Regex.

```
import re

url = '/s/GETTHISDATA/canBeIgnored/canBeIgnored'
myData = #needs to equal GETTHISDATA
```

Comment: `url.split("/")[2]`

Comment: `url`'s a string? If so then please put quotes around it

Comment: Do you always need the second level directory? What is it that distinguishes `GETTHISDATA` from, `canBeIgnored`?

Comment: @Asad, yes it will always be the second level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
>>> import re
>>> url = '/s/GETTHISDATA/canBeIgnored/canBeIgnored'
>>> re.findall('(?<=/).*?(?=/)', url)
['s', 'GETTHISDATA', 'canBeIgnored']
>>> re.findall('(?<=/).*?(?=/)', url)[1]
'GETTHISDATA'
>>>
```

What this does is capture zero or more characters (non-greedily) between two `/`'s.  To be clearer, here is a breakdown:

```
(?<=/) # Poisitive look-back assertion to test if text is preceded by a /
.*?    # Zero or more non-whitespace characters that are matched non-greedily
(?=/)  # Positive look-ahead assertion to test if text is followed by a /
```

However, a cleaner, non-Regex solution would be to just split on `/`:

```
>>> url.split('/')
['', 's', 'GETTHISDATA', 'canBeIgnored', 'canBeIgnored']
>>> url.split('/')[2]
'GETTHISDATA'
>>>
```

Personally, I'd use the second solution.  Regex just seems like overkill here.

Comment: this (the re solution) could return more than one result, if, for instance, you had a url like `/s/GETTHISDATA/notthis/orthis/`... you would get at least two results in that case, though the right one is still the first...

Comment: That's a good point.  I changed my code structure to capture for stuff between 2 /'s.  To tell you the truth though, I just gave the Regex solution 'cause the OP asked for Regex.  My _real_ answer is using `str.split`.